# Debian 8 performance problems with good hardware

Tags: debian, memory, performance, chrome

I bought about 6 months ago a good laptop (Lenovo ThinkPad E550 : Intel Core i5-5200U, 8 GO DDR3, AMD Radeon R7 M260) and installed Debian Jessie with Gnome 3  (no unity) on it. The system worked fine in the beginning, but more recently I'm having performance problems regularly.

It seems like there is a lot of memory used, and the laptop begin to slow over time until it's very near the freeze. Just now, I've boot up the laptop and launch Chrome + Webstorm and it's already 3.7 Go of memory used.

It's very annoying because I'm working as a web developer, and I need to launch VirtualBox in top of this. And often it slows really hard the system, where there should not. I think my hardware is more than sufficient for running IDE, browser and virtualbox

Do you have any idea?

P.S. : Here is a copy of `ps -au` command just now, maybe it helps:

```
    USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
Debian-+  1168  0.0  0.0 180104  4520 tty1     Ssl+ 09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-wayland-session
Debian-+  1253  0.0  0.0  43040  3872 tty1     S+   09:33   0:00 dbus-daemon --print-address 3 --s
Debian-+  1343  0.0  0.1 537320 12108 tty1     Sl+  09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-sess
Debian-+  1415  0.2  1.6 1764780 132332 tty1   Sl+  09:33   0:01 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
Debian-+  1788  0.0  0.6 258936 47584 tty1     Sl+  09:33   0:00 /usr/bin/Xwayland :1024 -rootless
Debian-+  1797  0.0  0.0 337800  5588 tty1     Sl+  09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-
Debian-+  1802  0.0  0.0  42828  3704 tty1     S+   09:33   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-fil
Debian-+  1804  0.0  0.0 209212  6412 tty1     Sl+  09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-reg
Debian-+  1834  0.0  0.4 917420 34952 tty1     Sl+  09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gn
jeremy    1889  0.0  0.0 192256  5488 tty2     Ssl+ 09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session --run
jeremy    1891  4.6  1.0 415632 86012 tty2     Sl+  09:33   0:39 /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg vt2 -displayfd
root      1895  0.0  0.0   4068   756 tty2     S+   09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/xserver-xorg-video-intel
jeremy    1905  0.2  0.0  44416  5264 tty2     S+   09:33   0:02 dbus-daemon --print-address 4 --s
jeremy    1907  0.0  0.1 545900 12596 tty2     Sl+  09:33   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-session/gnome-sess
jeremy    1954  0.0  0.0 337808  5480 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi-bus-
jeremy    1959  0.0  0.0  42960  3972 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --config-fil
jeremy    1962  0.0  0.0 209108  5368 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/at-spi2-core/at-spi2-reg
jeremy    1976  5.4  3.5 2359564 284608 tty2   Sl+  09:34   0:47 /usr/bin/gnome-shell
jeremy    1980  0.0  0.0 275536  6396 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd
jeremy    1985  0.0  0.0 343248  4988 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-fuse /run/use
jeremy    2014  0.0  0.1 605636 13944 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-shell/gnome-shell-
jeremy    2028  0.0  0.2 595912 20240 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-sour
jeremy    2030  0.0  0.0 178628  4568 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/dconf/dconf-service
jeremy    2037  0.0  0.1 454940 11104 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/telepathy/mission-contro
jeremy    2042  0.0  0.3 746520 28032 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/go
jeremy    2047  0.0  0.1 346540 10224 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-udisks2-volume
jeremy    2065  0.0  0.1 411244  9160 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-afc-volume-mon
jeremy    2075  0.0  0.0 262700  5128 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-mtp-volume-mon
jeremy    2080  0.0  0.0 260616  4856 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-goa-volume-mon
jeremy    2089  0.0  0.0 358996  7352 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-online-accounts/go
jeremy    2096  0.0  0.0 274864  5648 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfs-gphoto2-volume
jeremy    2103  0.0  0.4 1201388 38692 tty2    Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gn
jeremy    2120  0.0  0.7 824828 57524 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-cale
jeremy    2121  0.0  0.1 414988 12672 tty2     SNl+ 09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-us
jeremy    2123  0.0  0.1 483200 11112 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gs
jeremy    2124  0.0  0.5 1029496 44416 tty2    Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-alar
jeremy    2135  0.2  0.2 581184 22696 tty2     SNl+ 09:34   0:01 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-extract
jeremy    2139  1.2  0.7 452524 59292 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:10 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-store
jeremy    2144  0.0  0.1 983368 12344 tty2     SNl+ 09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-ap
jeremy    2145  0.3  0.2 1045712 19852 tty2    SNl+ 09:34   0:02 /usr/lib/tracker/tracker-miner-fs
jeremy    2146  0.2  1.2 800964 99468 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:02 /usr/bin/gnome-software --gapplic
jeremy    2149  0.0  0.3 239744 31088 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/syste
jeremy    2150  0.0  0.1 562352 14008 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 zeitgeist-datahub
jeremy    2164  0.0  0.6 880672 50128 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-cale
jeremy    2186  0.0  0.2 671408 17996 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addr
jeremy    2188  0.0  0.6 799512 49496 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-cale
jeremy    2194  0.0  0.0 415348  6972 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/bin/zeitgeist-daemon
jeremy    2212  0.0  0.2 798292 18916 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/evolution/evolution-addr
jeremy    2240  0.0  0.1 321276 15216 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/zeitgeist/zeitgeist-fts
jeremy    2286  0.1  0.4 589508 33696 tty2     Sl+  09:34   0:01 /usr/lib/gnome-terminal/gnome-ter
jeremy    2370  0.0  0.0  23444  5116 pts/0    Ss   09:34   0:00 bash
jeremy    2451 10.0  2.9 1178928 234792 tty2   SLl+ 09:34   1:24 /opt/google/chrome/chrome
jeremy    2458  0.0  0.0   5968   772 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 cat
jeremy    2459  0.0  0.0   5968   760 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 cat
jeremy    2515  0.0  0.0   6368   804 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
jeremy    2540  0.0  0.5 361772 47168 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    2646  0.0  0.0   6368   780 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
jeremy    2647  0.0  0.1 144520  9568 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/nacl_helper
jeremy    2821  0.0  0.1 361772 11044 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    2824  0.0  0.0  62448  5656 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconf/g
jeremy    2856  5.0  1.9 813020 157948 tty2    Sl+  09:34   0:41 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --enabl
jeremy    2860  0.0  0.1 390980 12936 tty2     S+   09:34   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    2908  0.0  0.0  23528  5364 pts/1    Ss   09:34   0:00 bash
jeremy    2974  2.7  2.1 945680 169868 tty2    Sl+  09:34   0:22 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    2980  5.1  2.4 956272 192196 tty2    Sl+  09:34   0:42 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    3046  1.2  1.9 984092 152784 tty2    Sl+  09:34   0:10 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    3115  3.6  6.0 1361076 481476 tty2   Sl+  09:34   0:30 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    3127  0.3  1.5 1124320 124524 tty2   Sl+  09:34   0:02 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    3317  0.0  0.0 349164  6468 tty2     Sl+  09:35   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-burn --spawne
jeremy    3325  0.0  0.0 186768  5244 tty2     Sl+  09:35   0:00 /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd-metadata
jeremy    3666  0.7  1.5 1459432 120932 tty2   Sl+  09:36   0:04 /usr/lib/slack/slack --disable-gp
jeremy    3681  0.0  0.3 304052 29872 tty2     S+   09:36   0:00 /usr/lib/slack/slack --type=zygot
jeremy    3715  0.4  1.9 1136220 151032 tty2   Sl+  09:36   0:02 /usr/lib/slack/slack --type=rende
jeremy    3739  1.2  3.4 1314916 271416 tty2   Sl+  09:36   0:09 /usr/lib/slack/slack --type=rende
jeremy    4489  0.0  0.0   4308  1504 tty2     S+   09:38   0:00 /bin/sh /opt/webstorm2016/bin/web
jeremy    4544 12.6  5.5 4495020 435484 tty2   Sl+  09:38   1:13 /opt/webstorm2016/bin/../jre/jre/
jeremy    4585  0.0  0.0   5896  2860 tty2     S+   09:38   0:00 /opt/webstorm2016/bin/fsnotifier6
jeremy    4709  0.1  0.5 1077508 43084 pts/1   Sl+  09:39   0:00 npm
jeremy    4725  0.0  0.0   4312   792 pts/1    S+   09:39   0:00 sh -c gulp build --serve --verbos
jeremy    4726  2.4  2.1 1293036 166132 pts/1  Sl+  09:39   0:13 gulp
jeremy    5291  2.6  0.5 515252 45808 tty2     Sl+  09:43   0:07 gnome-system-monitor
jeremy    5359  7.4  1.7 847040 136276 tty2    Sl+  09:43   0:20 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    5384  2.1  1.7 847772 138996 tty2    Sl+  09:44   0:05 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    5401  0.2  0.4 523344 38588 tty2     Sl+  09:44   0:00 /opt/google/chrome/chrome --type=
jeremy    5595  0.0  0.0  36104  3176 pts/0    R+   09:48   0:00 ps -au
```

**htop result**

[image]

Comment: Install and run the `htop` command, it'll tell you which process is clogging the memory.

Comment: I added it to the question, looks like chrome is eating a lot...

Comment: Please add to the post, How many tabs in chrome, and why virtualbox? Do you have an email client running too? How big the mailbox?

Comment: No tabs in Chrome, it's just after launch ; virtualbox is needed for photoshop, anyway it shouldn't be a problem to run 3 softwares with my hardware..
I don't have email client

Comment: Does the slowdown happen if _chrome_ is run without _webstorm_?

Comment: Yep , same thing